# Choice of power supply block for RPI4 PCB and sensors

Tags: power-supply, raspberry-pi

My project consists of making analog to digital conversion from 10 sensors ([2 MyoWare sensors](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Biometric/MyowareUserManualAT-04-001.pdf) and [8 FSR sensors.](https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/3899023/Interlinkelectronics%20November2017/Docs/Datasheet_FSR.pdf)) with a Raspberry Pi4. The analog to digital conversion chips are [2 ADS1299](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads1299.pdf?ts=1604485750366).

I need to power them with the bipolar mode +2.5V/-2.5V. I have 2 choices: two 9V batteris or a power bank 5V 3A.

How can I know if the two 9V batteries can support powering all the system (sensors,RPI4,ADS1299?)

What must I calculate to choose the optimal power supply system?

Comment: Build and test. If you have to build it anyway, what's the problem? Or calculate the current taken by the circuit and see how long it takes to use up 50% of the available Ah rating of the battery. But, before you do that you should consider accepting the best answers to your previous questions. This site is free but there are certain expectations on the person asking the question (should they require ongoing support) and upvoting good answers and formally accepting the best answer is one of them.

Comment: There is no way little 9v transistor radio batteries will run a pi.  Probably you want a multi-output power supply with several amps for the +5v rail and an -5v one and then you can use small linear regulators to power the ADCs from that.

Answer (score 1):

EMG sensors : Single Supply +2.9V to +5.7V   (low current)
FSR & ADS1299's Unipolar or Bipolar Supplies: Analog: 4.75 ~ 5.25 V Digital: 1.8 ~ 3.6 V

"*I need to power them with the bipolar mode +2.5V/-2.5V.*"
Not really. Can you choose 5V=Vref and Vref/2 as your DC and AC ground reference ?
; or some ratio like this with DC bias to Vref/2.  "ground" =  "relative" 0V.

For EMG and FSR with long wires, you also want medically rated isolation from grid and SMPS noise, so battery power is best with such as 5V Power Bank with 3.3V LDO for Digital.

Always be conservative for Wh capacity for rPi then enjoy longer debug hours. ;)

Using charger at the same time would result in serious S/N degradation and even with shielded twisted pairs everywhere with large CM Chokes. (Consider Cat 6 cable with connectors and ground shields in use)

- 10nF RF Cap to AC ground helps reduce RF noise from 3.6 to 5V SMPS converter noise and ,

  - may need special attention to layout, ground, minimize crosstalk and muscle galvanic skin response,  CM chokes , minimize
    wire loop area, antenna effects, use quality electrode pads and/or with right leg drive, RLD to cancel CM noise.

### rPi 4 power specs

https://raspi.tv/2019/how-much-power-does-the-pi4b-use-power-measurements